# Why does a single select query result in multiple database transactions?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database, pgadmin

[image: Database statistics]

I connect to my postgres database through pgAdmin and run this query below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PICTURES;
```

I have about 450k rows in the table and the "tuples out" graph above reflects that.
Why does a single select query result in ~10 transactions as seen by transactions per second graph ? According to what I know it should be a single transaction ?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) PS [mre]

Comment: what's the DDL (Create table) for pictures?  Is it a partitioned table?  If partitioned maybe it's getting a count from each and then summing them.

Comment: Perhaps pgAdmin says that if a query runs in 0.1 seconds, that is 10 transactions per second. But I'd doubt that. You'd have to look at the pgAdmin source to see what they are measuring.